# Is it okay to read date from database in the view template in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am revisiting the basics of MVC and Ruby on Rails. I am looking at my code and found that I have used this select tag in my Edit User Profile view.

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">

              <div class="panel-heading">
                <%= f.label :country_id, "From*" %>
              </div>  

              <div class="panel-body">   
                <%= f.select :country_id, Country.order(:name).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I am accessing the Country table in the view. I am pretty sure this should not be done but somehow it works. Why does it work? What is the correct way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: It's recommended to avoid making db queries in the view,  but it works just fine. Better to write the query in the controller and expose it using an instance variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why what you have won't work. Remember, a view template is an "embedded ruby" file. It has Ruby embedded in an HTML template. When the view is "rendered" by the controller, all of the code inside it gets executed and whatever output is generated by its Ruby code becomes part of the HTMl document. In this case, the output generated by the Ruby code is a bunch of HTML tags and Country names and IDs.

To avoid having this logic in the view, you would put it in the controller and save it to an instance variable (i.e. something like `@select_vals`) and then reference that variable in the view template.

Answer (score 1):

It works because Rails provides a lot of 'magic' under the hood; this functionality, at a guess, is probably part of the ActionView library (I haven't checked).

One of the fundamental principles of the MVC model is that you don't do this in the view. This logic should be done in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way ->

in Controller method:

```
@country_vals = Country.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id)
```

**No need to use collect().**

In your view:

```
<%= f.select :country_id, @country_vals, {}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
```